# Dynamically populate variable number of sprites on grid layout group

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, 2d, grid-layout

As the title suggests, I'm trying to populate a UI panel with a `GridLayoutGroup` component at runtime with sprites from the resources folder. The problem is that the sprites do not auto-align to the grid cells, instead getting drawn on the center of the panel.

I've tried the approach mentioned [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/942546/add-item-to-gridlayoutgroup-using-instantiate.html) but it does not work for me. Here is the script I've attached to the gui with the `GridLayoutGroup`:

```c#
public class SpriteList : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gridPanel;
    public const string sortingLayer = "Foreground";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Sprite[] spriteArray = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites");
        RectTransform gridRT = gridPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        for (int i = 0; i < spriteArray.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject cellObject = new GameObject();
            cellObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            cellObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spriteArray[i];
            cellObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingLayerName = sortingLayer;

            GameObject sprite = (GameObject) Instantiate(cellObject);
            sprite.transform.SetParent(gridPanel.transform, false);
            LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate( 
                    gridPanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>());
            sprite.transform.localScale = new Vector3(30, 30, 1);
    }
}
```

Changing the settings of the `GridLayoutGroup` do not modify the behaviour I'm seeing at all.

Since everything I see online seems to indicate that the key is the line

```c#
sprite.transform.SetParent(gridPanel.transform, false);
```

which I use, what am I missing?

Much gratitude!

Answer (score 0):

Your objects should have a 'Layout Element' component attached.

After setting the parent of the objects call `LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate()` on the parent.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work (I also updated my post to include the new code). Do you know why this might be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a rect transform prefab with a `SpriteRenderer` attached, and then instantiating copies of the prefab and assigning the desired sprite at runtime. I'm not sure why my old approach did not work (I think I am missing something very fundamental) but here is the code I'm using now:

```
public GameObject gridPanel;
public const string sortingLayer = "Foreground";
public GameObject prefab;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    Sprite[] spriteArray = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprites");
    GameObject newObj;

    for (int i = 0; i < spriteArray.Length; i++)
    {
        newObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, transform);
        newObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spriteArray[i];
        newObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingLayerName = sortingLayer;
        LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(gridPanel.transform as RectTransform);
    }
}
```

I should mention that this approach has introduced/uncovered a new issue which is that the sizing and spacing of the sprites is way off. I've been trying to fix this for a while now with no success; I'll continue to try and post my solution here when I determine it, or else ask a separate question and post a link to that here.